# CodeIgniter view loading not loading in order?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I have a Controller in CodeIgniter with the following code:

```
$this->load->view("first");
echo "LOL";
$this->load->view("second");
```

But strangely, when the page is rendered, the HTML is:

```
LOL
<div id="firstView"></div>
<div id="secondView"></div>
```

I have no idea what could be causing this reordering of the statements. Any suggestions? Might I have overlooked something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rendering views in code igniter is done at the end.
If you wish to render them as you go you can do

```
echo $this->load->view("first", array(), true);
echo "LOL";
echo $this->load->view("second", array(), true);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's simple:

```
$this->load->view("...");
```

will not immediately *display* the view. This happens later, what is one of the benefits of a MVC framework.

Comment: I usually use echo statements to see the flow of the page execution. I guess when you don't control the time when different elements are rendered, my strategy does not work. I will have to make a new view, with nothing but testing text, and just load that to check execution order.

Comment: Use a logfile, log framework or whatever! I expect CI has something like this

Comment: You could use something like phpchrome, to output variables, etc to the developer console.

Comment: I would suggest you to simply load one view that loads the others views inside it. Loading several views in a controller is often illogical in more ways than one.

Comment: @RobinCastlin Could you explain your reasoning? If we only include one view, we add one extra layer of abstraction that does not add any advantages, but adds lots of copy-pasted code.

Comment: Having the controller and view layer separated has many advantages. This are most of the reasons because you are using CI. If you have just a simple application which only shows some simple views, you are free to do it without a framework. (I would do so). Doing it the simple, but clean way has advantages as well of course

Comment: I usually include a view called `index`, and inside it load `header`, `footer` and `content`, where `content` is a `$this->load->view($str_content)` and pass `array('str_content' => 'home')` to the `index` view. Then you only need to call one view inside every controller function, instead of including `header` and `footer` too. Also gives better design imo.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve what you are trying, you have to pass a third param to the function $this->load->view(...), indicating that you'll receive the view in a variable, and not to display it immediatly.

Like this:

```
echo $this->load->view("first", NULL, TRUE);
echo "LOL";
echo $this->load->view("second", NULL, TRUE);
```

Look at the third param TRUE (the second is all the variables you want to pass to it).
Don't forget to print the result of the view with echo. This is very useful if you want to store the views and process them, or print them in the order you wish.

Comment: @Robin Castlin, you were faster than me :P

Comment: Yeah, but yours used capital `TRUE`, which I found more prettier :)

Comment: That's one of my fingerprints ;)

Comment: Mine too :P becomes better. Note that the only thing I did with accepted answer was to add `echo` to 1st and 3rd row.

Comment: Yep, but you were faster and your answer was accepted. I lost time formatting the code

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more elegant way to do this:

```
$this->load->view("first");
$this->output->append_output("LOL");
$this->load->view("second");
```

Using this will reduce rewrites of pre-written $this->load->view statements into echos. Hope it helps.