# Model gets loaded before view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, model

I have a controller in codeigniter pages.php

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        echo("<br>");
        $this->load->model("math");
        echo $this->math->add(1,2);
    }
}
```

**The model**: math.php

```
class math extends CI_Controller
{
    public function add($val1,$val2){
        return $val1+$val2;
    }
}
```

**The view**: header.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>fashion and style</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    echo("this is the header");
?>
```

As per the controller the code should output:

```
this is the header

number
```

but i get the output like:

```
number this is the header
```

Why?

Comment: class math extends CI_Controller ==> CI_Model is it spelling mistake!! just wanted to know...

Comment: Well anything u will echo out in controller or model will appear before any view as the view is rendered in index.php and displayed in the final step.

Comment: @GauravMehra how can you say that, is it in the documentation, please share a link

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter view loading not loading in order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421345/codeigniter-view-loading-not-loading-in-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will echo the string from the codeignitor controller directly, it will render the string before rendering the loaded views. If you want to do so, you can try like-

```
$str = $this->math->add(1,2);
$this->output->append_output($str);
```

Then your controller will look like-

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->model("math");
        $str = "<br>".$this->math->add(1,2);
        $this->output->append_output($str);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Controller:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        $this->load->model("math_model");
        $data['number'] = $this->math_model->add(1,2);

        $this->load->view('header',$data);

    }
}
```

the model math_model.php

Model:

```
class Math_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function add($val1,$val2){
        return $val1+$val2;
    }
}
```

the view header.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>fashion and style</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    echo("this is the header");
?>
echo("<br>");
<?php 
        echo $number;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

For model details have a look here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

For views have a look here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: Seems you also missed a key part of the doc: "Class names must have the first letter capitalized"

Comment: No its not this part, the answer lies on what is commented by @gauravmehra ( the second comment)

Comment: Views are buffered. When you echo something directly in a controller, it is sent before the buffer is flushed (therefore before the output containing the view is sent to the browser), that's why it appears before anything.

You shouldn't to this (sending a direct output/echoing something outside of views), you risk getting into troubles as soon as you use anything related to headers (redirect, cookies, CI's sessions...)